# What are the known ways of changing an audio signal that are not audible to humans?

Tags: audio

For instance, I believe we cannot detect global phase shifts.  And of course frequencies above ~20kHz or below ~20Hz.

I've heard of "frequency masking", but don't know much about it and would appreciate a brief explanation.

What else is there?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking

Comment: Another question related to your title is **audio [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)**; hiding information in audio, but you're not interested in that, right?